# c# - how can I get the data of sub XML node

Tags: c#, xml

I'am just learning c# and got a problem. I can get nearly all data. But how can I get the data of the category of this xml?

```html
<data>
<detail>
    <product id="183438053251143" type_ID="1" >
 <title>Test</title>
 <description>Testdescription</description>
 <category id="111" level_sub="TestSub" level_top="TestTopLevel"/>
   </product>
   <product id="183438053252420" type_ID="1">
 <title>Title2</title>
 <description>Testdescription</description>
 <category id="123" level_sub="TestSub2" level_top="TestTopLevel2"/>
   </product>
</detail>
</data>
```

That code works - but I found no solution in order to get the category data.

```html
var products = from product in xml.Descendants("product")
select product;

           foreach (var item in products)
           {

        productid = item.Attribute("id").Value;
               typeID = item.Attribute("type_ID").Value;

               string myproduct = string.Format("/data/detail/product[@id={0}]", productid );
               XmlNodeList productList = xmlnode.SelectNodes(myproduct);

                foreach (XmlNode xnprogram in productList)
                {
                    product_title = xnprogram["title"].InnerText.Trim();
                    product_title = product_title.Replace("'", "");

                    try
                    {
                        product_description = xnprogram["description"].InnerText.Trim();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        product_description = "";
                    }
  }
   }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "data" in `<category>` is all attributes, so you get it the same way you get other attributes (e.g,, `productid = item.Attribute("id").Value;`).

Comment: .Descendants("category") do you try this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var categoryElement=item.Element("category");
var idAttribute= categoryElement.Attribute("id");
var level_subAttribute=categoryElement.Attribute("level_sub");
....
```

Comment: Yeah, var categoryElement=item.Element("category"); works perfect and I can reach the data. So great, thank you so much! And such quick, incredible.